# Expo Go App just crashes when testing app on Android

Tags: android, react-native, logging, expo

I'm developing React Native app and trying to test my app on Android in Expo Go. In my app there are 2 screens A and B. When loading screen A it's ok but when I try to navigate to screen B by pressing button, the Expo Go just crashes and I even have no possibility to view logs and even see the next screen. On iOS it's fine but on every Android device it's impossible to view error log for me. How can I see error log, stacktace and so on when Expo Go crashes on Android? Thanks.

Comment: You can use logcat to get Android logs, but often they are not super helpful. If you recreate the project in vanilla React Native, you could open the Android project in Android Studio, where you would get better crash logs. I'm not sure if that's an option for you.

Comment: Are you using webview in Screen B? It has a bug with Android that crashes the app. If not, I would recomend to start commenting all the components in screen B, and then see if it loads fine. If so, try uncommenting one, then the other one, and so until you see the failure. But as mentioned above, you can see the logcat as well, use the debug functionality of react native, or try with Flipper to see the error

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, Android is super strict on bad style values.

For me, I had a style like...

```
const style = StyleSheet.create({
    textItem: {
        fontSize: 15,
        lineHeight: '0em',  // This was the issue, I guess its not a valid value. I changed it to 0 and it worked.
    }
});
```

I also had a few other issues where I was doing something like...

```
 justifyContent: 'start' // not a correct value. Changed to 'flex-start'
```

iOS would load fine but android would quit immediately.